# LINQ query to get count of joined record

Tags: c#, linq

Can somebody help me out writing a LINQ query to get record that are joined? I have two models below. I want to get requirements count that belong to given project and has one or more ProjectTest joined to it.

```
public class ProjectTest
{
    public int ProjectTestID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public String Objective { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String SubCategory { get; set; }
    public String Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectRequirement> ProjectRequirements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTestStep> ProjectTestSteps { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRequirement
{
    public int ProjectRequirementID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Req No.")]
    public String ProjectRequirementIDStr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Module")]
    public String ModuleName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTest> ProjectTests { get; set; }
}
```

I just tried to write it as follows but does not seem working.

```
db.ProjectRequirements
  .Where(e => e.ProjectID == activeProjectID && 
              e.ProjectTests
                 .Select(ept => ept.ProjectTestID)
                 .Count() > 0)
  .Select(e => e.ProjectRequirementID)
  .Count();
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Not expected output?

Comment: `.Count() > 0` is *suboptimal*, change it into `.Any()`

Comment: Doing a `Select` before a `Count` is pointless.

Comment: Do you mean `.Where(ept => ept.ProjectTestID == ..)`

Comment: is this working? db.ProjectRequirements
  .Where(e => e.ProjectID == activeProjectID && 
              e.ProjectTests.Count > 0)
  .Count();

Comment: You really need to give use example data, the output you get from your query, and what you expect.  Right now other than the redundant `Select`s I don't see an issue with your query, if you want the number of requirements for the active project that have tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are counting the number of `ProjectRequirement` objects that have a given id and that have at least 1 `ProjectTest`.

If you want to count the amount of `ProjectTest`s you have for a given `ProjectId`:

```
var number = db.ProjectRequirements.Where(e => e.ProjectID == activeProjectID)
                                   .Sum(e => e.ProjectTests.Count());
```